# Debian Wheezy youtube video missing on page

Tags: video, debian, adobe-flash, iceweasel

have just installed Debian Wheezy XFCE. Installed Flash via [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-linux-7-wheezy-install-flash-player/)

So I restarted IceWeasel, and I don't get the warning to install Flash now. But when on a YouTube video page, everything but the YouTube video loads. 
The pic here is the example.

[image: PiC]

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to install the Flash plugin package. Just run these commands to install and configure it:

```
$ apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
$ update-flashplugin-nonfree --install
```

#### References

- [FlashPlayer - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer)

Comment: slm, that didnt work. i had already installed it, just did the second line you gave.

Comment: @Alex - did you restart your browser?

Comment: yup and restarted the computer..

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your preferences:
`Preferences → Applications tab` and find entry with content type ( left side ) like `Shockwave Flash file`.

Make sure your action dropdown ( right side ) is set to `Use Shockwave Flash`